# How to fix this error while reading a large file ? Python

Tags: python

The file is the actresses section from the IMDB Database.
The error I receive while trying to read a particular line is :

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 2, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 3976: invalid continuation byte
```

The code is :

```
with open("actresses.list",encoding = 'utf-8') as i:
     lenlines=i.readlines()
lenlines = (len(lines)) 
import linecache
print(lenlines)
print(linecache.getline("actresses.list",5))
```

Comment: Your file doesn't contain UTF8 perhaps?

Comment: Although, you traceback doesn't fit your code. At all. It is as if WingIDE tripped over something, not your code.

Comment: Also, why are you reading all lines into `lenlines`, then *replacing* the lines with the length? I'd not use `linecache` for this task either; that module is firmly aimed at loading *python modules*, not your average file. It tokenizes files to find Python codec hints, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If it is from the IMDB website, which seems to use iso-8859-1, (`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`), try using this codec when you open the file.